# PDFBox iterate through COSObject

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am using the PDFBox library v3.0.0. As the final result, I want to extract the text associated to the tags contained in the /StructTreeRoot of the PDF file.
The idea is to extract the page reference (Pg) and the MCID reference (K number) to then search for this text in that page.

Right now I am struggeling to get this elements from the /StructTreeRoot. I can only get all the tags, but I do not know how I can read the information contained in these tags:
[image: PDFBoxDebugger]

When I am trying to keep navigating and convert the COSObjects contained in the COSArray to COSDictionary, I receive the Exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSObject cannot be cast to org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary

This is my code:

```
File file = new File("document.pdf");
      PDDocument originalDocument;
      originalDocument = Loader.loadPDF(file);

      PDDocumentCatalog catalog = originalDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
      PDStructureTreeRoot structTree = catalog.getStructureTreeRoot();
      
      COSBase KstructTree = structTree.getK();
      
      COSDictionary Kdict = (COSDictionary) KstructTree;
      COSBase tagsDict = Kdict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.K);
      COSArray tagsArray = (COSArray) tagsDict;
      Iterator<COSBase> iteratorTagsArray = tagsArray.iterator();
      
      while (iteratorTagsArray.hasNext()){
          COSBase object = iteratorTagsArray.next();
          System.out.println(object.getCOSObject().toString());
          
          COSDictionary object2 = (COSDictionary) object;
      }
    
     originalDocument.close();
```

How I must do this? Thank you!

Comment: call `getObject()` on a COSObject. (What you're trying is part of somewhat unknown territory. Have a look at the source of PDFMergerUtility and PDFMergerUtilityTest in the source code on how to navigate the /K tree)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The method getObjects seems not to be available, although is suppose to be acording the documentation, seems that I can only apply the metgod getCOSObject in the objects of my current code.
I also checked the classese PDFMergerUtility you are commenting, but haven't discovered yet how to do what I want. Will keep looking.

Comment: Hi again, just was capable to use the getObject() function, seems that you have to convert the object twice. Seems that now I can navigate through the sub elements this object originally contains, my new loop is:
while (iteratorTagsArray.hasNext()){
          COSBase object = iteratorTagsArray.next();
          System.out.println(object.getCOSObject().toString());
          
          COSObject obj = (COSObject) object.getCOSObject();
          COSBase base = obj.getObject();
          System.out.println(base);
          
      }
Thank you!

Comment: `getObject()` is only available on `COSObject` classes, which are indirect references (like "[12 0 R]). You have to check whether your entry is a COSObject instance or not.

Comment: Hi, understood, thank you. Is really difficult to understand the library as is too many different classes and functions. Now it was possible to extract the content stream associated to the page, now I am trying to see if some class offer some function to extract the stream given the MCID. Do you know if is any? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `PDFMarkedContentExtractor` might help. There are a few answers here with it.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I have to refine my code more, and improve the efficiency, but I was able to extract the text:
COSDictionary pageDict = (COSDictionary) obj_dict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.PG);
PDPage page = new PDPage(pageDict);
PDFMarkedContentExtractor extractor = new PDFMarkedContentExtractor();
extractor.processPage(page);
System.out.println("List stream: "+listStream);
Iterator<PDMarkedContent> iteratorListStream = listStream.iterator();
int i=0;
while (iteratorListStream.hasNext()){
System.out.println("Iterator contents: "+listStream.get(i).getContents());
i++
}